# PHP 7 vs PHP 5 — changes in functions

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I'm currently building a website for my university assignment using local server XAMPP running PHP 7.1.1 but then I just found out that the university server is running an older PHP server version (I believe PHP 5.x) and all my PHP functions won't work at all.

So I wonder: if I want to make it work with the university server, do I just need to change syntax to match PHP 5.x?  Because now I have no idea what are the differences between PHP 7.x and 5.x.

Can anyone clarify this for me?

Comment: Thank you so much for helping with my gramma lol, I'm international student therefore i have very poor English skill hehe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could start from [the official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.php), if you want to migrate from 5.x to 7.x

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply.....
I will try to change as much as I can but it look like it going to be really mess for me T^T